# Multiple CASE in SQL when adding a Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database with a table called 't'. in 't' there is a column called 'y', which contains a year, and a column called 'c' with an integer (names are for simplicity of the question). I'm trying to do the following:

Select all the rows from the table where 'y' is more than 1990, add a new column called 'x' to the selected rows **(not to 't' table)** and check b, in the following way (I've written in Java since I couldn't get the SQL CASE to work)

```
int current_year = (current year...)
if(current_year-year<=8 && c<20000)
x+= ((20000-c)/1000)+1

else if(current_year-year<=12 && c<17000)
x+= ((17000-c)/1000)+1

else if (c<14000)
x+= ((14000-c)/1000)+1
```

(Please note how x+= and not x= , because I need it for something else that is hard to explain)

I'm a beginner in SQL - I've tried writing a query but there were so many CASE in it I confused and never got it to work well. Also, I didn't manage to add the 'x' column to the selected rows. The only part that did work was

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE y>1990
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if logic would turn into something like this:

```
select (x +
         (case when current_year - year <= 8 and c < 20000 then ((20000 - c) / 1000) + 1
          end) +
         (case when current_year - year <= 12 and c < 17000 then ((20000 - c)/ 1000) + 1
          end) +
         (case when (c < 14000) then ((14000 - c)/ 1000) + 1
        ) as x
from . . .
```

A SQL `case` statement doesn't have the concept of altering a value within a statement (as in `+=`), so you just add the different components together conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement worked for me:

```
DECLARE @cy as int


SET @cy = YEAR(GETDATE())

SELECT CASE WHEN @cy-y <=8 AND c<20000
THEN  ((20000-c/1000)+1
ELSE CASE WHEN @cy-y<=12 AND c<17000
        THEN ((17000-c)/1000)+1
        ELSE CASE WHEN c<14000
                THEN ((14000-c)/1000)+1
            END
    END
END AS X
```